# ReflectionException Class emails does not exist php artisan queue:work

Tags: laravel-5

when I do `php artisan queue:work` I'm getting error

> ReflectionException        Class emails does not exist

Comment: in one of your jobs you might be instantiating a class `emails` which does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to update composer.

or try this - delete vendor folder and run.

```
composer update
```